# PHP script to calculate code128

Tags: php, barcode, code128

All over the web I can find examples how to generate bar code images using php.

However I need function which will transform string into code128 value so that I can use it in OpenOffice and Word, format it using code128 font and get real bar code.

Although theoretically I could code it myself I believe there are already good and tested solutions.

More precisely: I need script which would turn: "3870639399632" into "ÍFf_}Ç_È2yÎ".

Answer (score 3):

Try:
http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-php-class-203.html

Or if you are using PEAR you can use http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Barcode2

And there is http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/quick-php-script-to-generate-a-barcode and also http://www.barcodebakery.com/en

Comment: I didn't want to down vote your answer :( It might be useful. I will check tomorrow. It told me that I can vote again if you modify your answer.

Comment: You can "un-downvote" my answer by clicking the down arrow again.  And are you trying to generate a barcode image, parse a barcode image to read it's string value, or transform a string into code128? That was unclear.  But, all three should be answered in my links.

Comment: You last voted on this answer
6 hours ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited
(click on this box to dismiss) I can't undo it :( My intention was to transform string into code128.

Answer (score 0):

Use the composer package "hbgl/php-code-128-encoder".
https://packagist.org/packages/hbgl/php-code-128-encoder

```
$encoded = Code128Encoder::encode('ABC123456DEF');
assert ($encoded === 'ÌABCÇ,BXÈDEFqÎ');
```